# Can't connect to uvicorn running in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fastapi, uvicorn

This command runs, and allows me to hit my API on localhost:

`uvicorn server:app --reload`

However, when I run this in a docker container, I get an `ECONNREFUSED` (or socket hang up in postman).

`uvicorn server:app --host 0.0.0.0`

Curl returns this:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I can see this in the logs:

```
Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I am mapping the default port (8000) when running the docker container, `docker ps` shows:

```
0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp
```

Is there something obvious I am missing? If not, how can I start to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: seems like everything you show is right.  What is the curl command you're using?

Comment: Sorry, annoyingly I ended up figuring this out almost straight away. Oddly it was due to how much memory I was giving docker. Increasing it started it up fine.

I have a feeling this is due to the API itself and not related to uvicorn particularly. Leaving this here for anyone who finds this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this question all over the internet with different answers. It's always some kind of docker problem, and not a problem with the underlying containerized app.

The cause, for me, was that the `docker0` interface (the default docker bridge network) did not have an IP on the host. Containers would get IPs on the docker bridge network just fine, but couldn't communicate with the host, because it wasn't routable. This apparently also causes problems for docker port forwarding.

Hope this helps save somebody some hours of troubleshooting.